# How to count long days from one date to another date and insert to table of database using CI

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, strtotime

My Table in MySQL

I designed "survei_pohon" table and I set my 'submit_date' column has same values (default values, ex: 2013-02-28), and this is my table below:

```
id          survey_date           submit_date         long_day
 1           2013-02-18           2013-02-28             10
 2           2013-02-21           2013-02-28             10
 3           2013-02-25           2013-02-28             10
```

"id" column is 'integer' type, "survey_date" is 'date' type, "submit_date" is 'date' type, "long_day" is 'integer' type.

This my Model : 
`

```
function olah(){
$tanggal_survei="SELECT survey_date FROM survei_pohon";
$tanggal_sekarang="SELECT submit_date FROM survei_pohon";
$lama_hari="SELECT long_day FROM survei_pohon";


    $result = @mysql_query($tanggal_survei);
    $t = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    $results = @mysql_query($tanggal_sekarang);
    $u = mysql_fetch_array($results);

    $lama_hari = @mysql_fetch_array($lama_hari);

    $start = strtotime($t['tanggal_survei']);
    $end = strtotime($u['tanggal_sekarang']);

    $lama_hari = ($end - $start) / (60 * 60 * 24);

    $this->db->set('long_day', $lama_hari);
    $this->db->update('survei_pohon');        
}
```

}?>`

My expectation from my "survei_pohon" table is

```
id          survey_date           submit_date        long_day
 1           2013-02-18           2013-02-28             10
 2           2013-02-21           2013-02-28              7
 3           2013-02-25           2013-02-28              3
```

I'm guessing that there is something wrong in my model code. But I don't know how to fix that code. I'm expecting your help. Thanks for any help, this is difficult for me.

Comment: what output/error did u get?

Comment: Do you have to do this in PHP or would a mysql solution work?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a MySQL solution to update the db.

```
UPDATE survei_pohon SET long_day = submit_date - survey_date
```

Not sure you really need to store that field though since it's a calculation of other fields -- generally leave those for UI purposes.  In which case, you could just include it in your SELECT statement:

```
SELECT *, submit_date - survey_date long_day FROM survei_pohon
```

I know this doesn't address how to do it with your code, but seems a little easier.

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d040f/1).

Comment: OK, I understand with your explaining. thank you very much for this one. by the way, do you have any clue about fix this model above with PHP? how about with array in PHP and insert the PHP processing result into the database?